# Why does StoreContext.GetStoreProductsAsync(productKinds, storeIDs) get only current UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store

I have another UWP question.

I'm trying to get all the UWP apps that I published on the MS Store, but it seems there is something wrong: I can only get the current one beeing executed, although I insert many store IDs, the ones from my apps, as suggested by MS Docs.

Here's the code (of course, in my code I insert the real IDs):

```
            StoreContext context = StoreContext.GetDefault();

            string[] productKinds = { "Application" };
            List<String> filterList = new List<string>(productKinds);
            string[] storeIds = { "firstID", "secondID", "thirdID" };

            StoreProductQueryResult queryResult = await context.GetStoreProductsAsync(filterList, storeIds);

            if (queryResult.ExtendedError == null)
            {
                foreach (var product in queryResult.Products)
                {
                    // Do something with 'product'
                }
            }
```

Well, it only returns one item, the current one.

Is there a way to obtain even other store apps?
Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please, see my edited reply below.

Comment: Didn't know about these option. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetStoreProductsAsync` is only for the products associated with the app (i.e. add-ons):

> Gets Microsoft Store listing info for the specified products that are
>   *associated with the current app*.
>   [[docs]](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/Windows.Services.Store.StoreContext#Windows_Services_Store_StoreContext_GetStoreProductsAsync_)

To solve the problem you might want to look in the direction of [Microsoft Store collection API and purchase API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service) (requires web app setup in Azure).

Other than that `StoreContext` class at its current state doesn't contain API to get product information about other apps and their add-ons.